# Java Swing Timer getting faster and faster

Tags: java, swing, timer

I'm working on a small turn based RPG. For every turn, one of the two characters tries to hit the other character then 2000ms later, the timer restarts the *attack* method (to give time to the player to read the outcome of each turn). After the battle, the player goes back to the level map where he can choose to move away or initiate another battle. Here's my problem: Every time the player initiates a new battle, the Timer delay is shorter and shorter so the battle happens too fast at some point. First fight, each turn will be 2 seconds, then 1 second, then 500ms, and so on. Here's my code, what am I missing?

```
public void attack(Character a, Character d) {


    //Calculations//////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////unit a (attacker)////////////////////////
    Weapon aWep = (Weapon) a.inventory[0];

    double aCritRate = (double) (a.skl / 2 + aWep.crit - d.lck) / 100;
    double aHitRate = (double) (aWep.acc + (a.skl * 2) + (a.lck / 2)) / 100;
    double aAvoidRate = (double) (a.spd * 2 + a.lck) / 100;
    int aAttackPower = (a.pow + aWep.dmg);
    boolean aTwice = a.spd >= d.spd + 4 ? true : false;

    ///////////////////unit d (defender)////////////////////////
    Weapon dWep = (Weapon) d.inventory[0];

    double dCritRate = (double) (d.skl / 2 + dWep.crit - a.lck) / 100;
    double dHitRate = (double) (dWep.acc + (d.skl * 2) + (d.lck / 2)) / 100;
    double dAvoidRate = (double) (d.spd * 2 + d.lck) / 100;
    int dAttackPower = (d.pow + dWep.dmg);
    boolean dTwice = d.spd >= a.spd + 4 ? true : false;

    int delay = 2000;
    Timer timer;

    ActionListener repeat = new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            switch(bturn){
                case(1):attack(d,a); break;
                default:break;


            }
        }
    };

    timer = new Timer(delay,repeat);

    //Battle/////////////////////////

    int aDmg = aAttackPower - d.def;
    double aHitChance = aHitRate - dAvoidRate;
    String sound;

    //Turn 1

    if (aHitChance >= rngs[rngsIndex]) {

        if (aCritRate >= rngs[rngsIndex]) {
            aDmg *= 3;
            sound="crit.wav";
            t.print("Critical Hit! " + a.name + " attacks " + d.name + " for " + aDmg + " damage!");
            rngsIndex++;
        } else {
            sound="hit.wav";
            t.print(a.name + " attacks " + d.name + " for " + aDmg + " damage!");
            rngsIndex++;
        }

        d.damageHp(aDmg);
        rngsIndex++;
    } else {
        sound = "miss.wav";
        t.print(a.name + " has missed.");
        rngsIndex++;
    }

    playSound(sound);

    if (d.isDead) {
        String add = t.text.getText();
        add+=" " + d.name + " has been killed.";
        t.print(add);
        a.xp+=35;
        charPane.set(a);
        grid[d.x][d.y].removeMouseListener(grid[d.x][d.y].hover);
        killUnit(d, grid[d.x][d.y]);
    }

    if (d.faction.equals("e")) {
        enemPane.set(d);
    } else {
        charPane.set(d);
    }

    //Turn 2
    bturn++;
    if(!d.isDead && bturn==1){
        System.out.println("REACHED");
        timer.start();
    }

    else{
        timer.stop();
        bturn = 0;
        grid[d.x][d.y].removeActionListener(grid[d.x][d.y].targetable);
        clearGrid();
        loop();
    }


}
```

Comment: You've got almost a recursion going on here, where the attack method is creating a Timer instance which then calls attack which then creates **another** timer instance, which calls attack..., and I don't think that you want to do this. You need to re-think and then re-wire this code.

Comment: Note that no-where do you stop the timer, so you're going to have many many timers running as this program runs.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I do have a timer.stop(); in the last _else_ statement

Comment: OK, didn't see that, but regardless, this code needs to be re-factored. Work out the logic and code flow on paper first and then commit to code.

Comment: Thank you! I just created a `battle` method, managing the timer and the battle turns and calling the `attack` method and now everything works fine! :)

Comment: @SimonBesozzi `and now everything works fine!` - your welcome for the help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45571802/using-a-java-swing-timer-just-to-delay-a-function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to log which instance of ActionListener repeat caused the attack. I think you will see, that the speedup is caused by having more instances of Timer and ActionListener then you want.

After each run, number of those instances doubles, hence the exponencial growth of number of turns per second.

In absence of logger:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("" + LocalDateTime.now() + " " + this);
        switch(bturn){
```